# rdlc two table

Tags: rdlc

i want to use two table on my rdlc report .....one table contain just group another one contain header,detail and footer fields like:

```
Table 1

DivisionName  DistrictName  ThanaName

    Table 2  
    Name ID Address 


    Output look like


    **D    D    T**-----------Table 1 Output on basis of table 1 group basis
    A   001   ade-------------Table 2
    B   002   ade

    **D   M    T**
    C   003   ade
    D   004   aew
```

Answer (score 1):

Best approach for this is to combine the tables into one datatable joining on key.  Here is an example of a Dataset Helper from Microsoft to [combine DataSets](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326080/en-us).  Take note of the related content for other Dataset Helper examples.

You can then nests lists in RDLC designer grouping as necessary on division, etc.